# How to serve html scripts via flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I've been trying to connect my html script to flask via the /static folder I made, but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason?

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'assets/js/main.js')}}"></script>
```

each time I run my main I get a 404 error saying

```
GET /static/assets/js/main.js' HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

my directories:

- app

  - main.py
  - static

    - assets

      - js

        - main.js

  - templates

    - index.html

here is my main.py, very basic, just starting to learn flask:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/home")
    @app.route("/")
    def home():
        return render_template("index.html")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

I've been searching around for a few hours, but even my error message seems like it should be able to find the folder? Very confused

Comment: Your scripts link looks fine. Show the `index.html` file code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adjusting your script tag like this:

`<script src="{% url_for('static', filename='assets/js/main.js' %}"></script>`

Can you also post your `index.html` and `main.js`?

**Edit:** just tried to reproduce your steps and found no errors when using virtualenv from the parent directory. Should look something like this:

```
app
├── main.py
├── templates
|   └── index.html
└── static
    └── assets
        └── js
            └── main.js
venv
```